# Partition table & filesystem for a USB flash drive

Tags: filesystems, devices

I've got a USB flash drive I want to use on printers, audio equipment, and other various devices.

In my experience, most Linux is very forgiving about what partition table and FS type I use on my flash drives, but other non-linux devices aren't so nice in that regard and my flash drive is usually rejected by these things.

I realize it won't be supported by everything, but I want this flash drive to be as close as possible to factory settings as I can get.

- What partition table is usually set on USB flash drives out of the box?
- What FS type usually is set on USB flash drives out of the box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I've only seen msdos partition tables (MBR) on new flash drives.
2. It's usually FAT32. But you can only store files up to 4GB in size on this fs type. I would go for NTFS or exFAT instead, but this depends on the compatibility of your devices.